# How to make the checkbox to cover 100% width and 100% height of a sqaure container?

Tags: html, css, layout, checkbox, position

I've been able to place a checkbox on top of a dynamically sized (responsive) div but now I need to make it so that the checkbox covers 100% width and 100% height of this div.

Here is my codepen: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/yadEOP
where at the moment I just temporarily hardcoded the width and the height of the checkbox.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#container {
  width: 50%;
  border: solid 4px tomato;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need create a *stacking context* for the checkbox, then you add width and height of 100%. Done.

`#container { 
 /*create stacking context first*/ 
 position: relative;
}`

`input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}`

Full example: [codepen](http://codepen.io/jotavejv/pen/bwPKrW)

Answer (score 0):

parent div:

```
.checkboxes {
    position: relative;
}
```

the input in it:

```
.checkboxes .checks {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

that way you hide the checkbox, make it take the width and the height of the parent, hide it with the opacity value (important - display: none and visibility: hidden will not do the job) and make it clickable. voila :)